# How to properly downgrade an existing Drupal installation to a lower PHP version?

Tags: composer

I've got a site smoothly running on Drupal 9.4.8 and PHP 8.1. Now I would like to enable APCu in PHP, but my provider unfortunately has installed APCu for PHP 8.0 only. If I simply switch to PHP 8.0, my Drupal installation gives me a an error message:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".

Which steps do I have to do, in order to make my site work in PHP 8.0?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the platform on which you set dependencies is running a different version of PHP than 8.0, you do the following:

1. Ensure that if there is a direct `php` dependency in the `requires` section of `composer.json`, that it is `>=8.0` or similar.
2. Set a [target platform version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) with `composer config platform.php 8.0.24`. The specific version you put here does not have to match the server platform's version exactly.
3. `composer update`.